# Pass variable inside ruby command?

Tags: ruby, linux

`prueban8` file content is:

```
 $F[1] > "2" and $F[1] < "4" and $F[3] == "pet"
```

Code is:

```
ruby -a -F ';' -ne 'input = File.read("prueban8"); eval (input); puts  $F[2] end' ppp.txt
```

but I cant pass variable appears error
, unexpected end-of-input

How can I solve this?

Comment: I am curious as to the advantage of putting the code in another file when it would have been quicker to just include it in the script you have written?

Comment: I am  using a variable from jquery serialize command throught sinatra framework

Comment: for filter data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this

```
ruby   -a   -F';' -ne      'input = File.read("prueban8")   ; eval ( input +  " ; puts  $F[2] end")   '  ppp.txt
```